# Authorize on Ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I have MVC5 project and I have some ajax call when clicking a button, the controller it called have custom attribute I made so the framework can redirect someone to login page similar to non-ajax `[Authorize]`.

Custom Attribute:

```
public class AjaxAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
            dynamic urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context.RequestContext);
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;

            context.Result = new JsonResult {
                Data = new {
                    Error = "NotAuthorized",
                    LogOnUrl = urlHelper.Action("Registration", "Membership")
                },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        } else {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost()]
[AjaxAuthorize()]
public void Test()
{
       //do something
}
```

Javascript :

```
    //AJAX AUTHORIZE REDIRECT
    $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr) {
        if (xhr.status == 403) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
            window.location = response.LogOnUrl;
        }
    });
```

it works fine in my localhost, however it doesn't work when I deployed it to my webserver. I did some checking and turned out the `xhr.responseText` in my jquery script have different result, here's the comparison :

localhost :

```
{"Error":"NotAuthorized","LogOnUrl":"/Membership/Registration"} //correct output
```

webserver :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have custom error pages in the web.config set to remoteonly as this could cause this behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to ``off`` but it is still giving me same error because the responsetext result isn't in json format.

Comment: if you have `httpErrors` element in `system.webServer`, comment it out too. Also you're assigning a `403` status code to response, you should comment it too. I know it's bad practice but it will most probably solve your issue. You'll then have to check for `Error` property in `success` callback of `Ajax` call

Comment: Your server is overtaking responses for Http Errors.

Comment: @ShoaibShakeel: can you give me a code example? I'm kinda confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1** (Preferred)

You can set `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` to true for your Responses. Like this:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext context)
{
    if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
        dynamic urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context.RequestContext);

        context.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors= true;
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;

        context.Result = new JsonResult {
            Data = new {
                Error = "NotAuthorized",
                LogOnUrl = urlHelper.Action("Registration", "Membership")
            },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    } else {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(context);
    }
}
```

**Method 2**
You can Stop Sending end HTTP Status Code `403` by removing this statement from `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`.

```
context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
```

This will tell your client and server this this request has succeeded. In that case your javascript code would be look something like this,

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (e, xhr) {
    var response = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
    if (typeof(response.Error) !== 'undefined') {
        window.location = response.LogOnUrl;
    }
});
```

Comment: Method 1 work like a charm. Can you tell me what actually happened when ``TrySkipIisCustomErrors`` is set to true? THANKS!

Comment: For more details looke here: https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/custom-404-page-ignored-by-iis-7/