# Redirect to Authorize Controller with Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, jwt

I have an issue and need some clarity. I have an AccountController with a Login action that processes a login, and if it is successful, it redirects the user to the home page which I want it to be protected with a jwt. So my question is this, I know I redirect to my Home/Index properly, but I'm missing something to Authenticate the token provided. 1. What attribute tag do I need to add to the top of the HomeController Class? 2. How can I pass with the '@Url.Action("Index","Home")'?

***EDIT: After successful login, it says I’ve successfully logged in, but since I require the token to be in the headers, when I try to redirect with @Url.Action(), it sends the Bad Request cause I’m not sure how to populate headers with that.***

Here is the Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Chat.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace Chat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "localhost",
                    ValidAudience = "localhost",
                    IssuerSigningKey = AccountController.SIGNING_KEY
                };
            });

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the AccountController with the Login Action:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Chat.Models;
using Chat.DatabaseAccessObject;
using Chat.Identity;
using Chat.DatabaseAccessObject.CommandObjects;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace Chat.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private const string SECRET_KEY = "CHATSECRETKEY";
        public static SymmetricSecurityKey SIGNING_KEY = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SECRET_KEY));
        private ServerToStorageFacade serverToStorageFacade = new ServerToStorageFacade();
        private AuthenticateUser authenticateUser = new AuthenticateUser();

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var mapLoginModelToUser = new MapLoginModelToUser();
                var user = await mapLoginModelToUser.MapObject(loginModel);

                // If login user with those credentials does not exist
                if(user == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                else
                {
                    var result = await this.authenticateUser.Authenticate(user);

                    if(result.Result == Chat.Enums.AuthenticateResult.Success)
                    {
                        // SUCCESSFUL LOGIN
                        // Creating and storing cookies

                        var token = Json(new
                        {
                            data = this.GenerateToken(user.Email, user.PantherID),
                            redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index","Home"),
                            success = true
                        });
                        return Ok(token);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Unsuccessful login
                        return Unauthorized();
                    }
                }
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }
       private string GenerateToken(string email, string pantherId)
        {
            var claimsData = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Actor, pantherId) };

            var signInCredentials = new SigningCredentials(SIGNING_KEY, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "localhost",
                audience: "localhost",
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
                claims: claimsData,
                signingCredentials: signInCredentials
            );

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Error() => View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
```

Here is the Index.cshtml located in '/Views/Account/Index.cshtml':

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

@model Chat.Models.LoginModel

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/Login.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="text-center">
    <form id="formSubmit" method="post" class="form-signin">
        <img class="mb-4" src="~/images/Chat-Curved.png" alt="" width="150" height="150">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.inputEmail, new { @class = "form-control", @type="email", @placeholder = "Email address", @required = "required", @autofocus = "" })
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.inputPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @type="password", @placeholder = "Password", @required = "required"})
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
            <label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.rememberMe)  Remeber me
            </label>
        </div>
        <button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the HomeController With the Index Action:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Chat.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Login.js that is referenced by the Index.cshtml:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formSubmit").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#inputEmail").val();
        var password = $("#inputPassword").val();
        var remember = $("#rememberMe").val();
        var loginModel = {
            inputEmail: email,
            inputPassword: password,
            rememberMe: remember
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Account/Login',
            data: JSON.stringify(loginModel),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
            success: function (response) {
                var token = response.value.data;
                localStorage.setItem("token", token);
                window.location.href = response.value.redirectUrl;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authorize on Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554865/authorize-on-ajax-call)

Comment: Try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/q/29554865/395675. This worked for me .

Comment: On successul login, it tries to redirst to the url Home/Index, but after it says I successfully logged in, it doesn’t redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authorise your controller, you have to use a middle ware (**ActionFilterAttribute**), which will detect user's http request and validate them by decoding user's token. you can filter all http methods (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE...etc), and can implement your own authorisation logic for specific http method.

**AuthorizationRequiredAttribute.cs**

N.B: here all codes are not relevant to your problem. but hope you'll understand.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class AuthorizationRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IAccessTokenServices _accessTokenServices;
    private readonly IPermissionServices _permissionServices;
    private readonly IAuditLogServices _auditLogServices;
    private IConfiguration _config;
    public AuthorizationRequiredAttribute(IAccessTokenServices accessTokenServices, IPermissionServices permissionServices,
        IAuditLogServices auditLogServices,IConfiguration config)
    {
        _accessTokenServices = accessTokenServices;
        _config = config;
        _permissionServices = permissionServices;
        _auditLogServices = auditLogServices;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(Constants.HttpHeaders.Token))
            {
                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var token = handler.ReadToken(context.HttpContext.Request.Headers[Constants.HttpHeaders.Token])
                    as JwtSecurityToken;
                var expireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == Constants.JwtClaims.ExpiresOn).Value);
                if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method == WebRequestMethods.Http.Get)
                {
                    if (expireDate < DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    var accessToken = _accessTokenServices
                        .Details(x => x.Token == context.HttpContext.Request.Headers[Constants.HttpHeaders.Token]);
                    if (accessToken != null)
                    {
                        if (accessToken.ExpiresOn < DateTime.Now)
                        {
                            _accessTokenServices.Delete(accessToken);
                            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var userId = Convert.ToInt32(token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == Constants.JwtClaims.UserId).Value);
                            var userTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == Constants.JwtClaims.UserTypeId).Value);
                            if (accessToken == null)
                            {
                                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                            }
                            else if (!_permissionServices.IsPermissionExist(context.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString(), userTypeId))
                            {
                                context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                _auditLogServices.Save(context.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString(), userId);
                                accessToken.ExpiresOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt16(_config["Jwt:ExpiresOn"]));
                                _accessTokenServices.UpdateExpireTime(accessToken);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestResult();
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

}

**HomeController.cs**

Now you can use AuthorizationRequiredAttribute as api/controller filter service. i have modified your controller and see the Message method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Chat.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/home")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet("message"), ServiceFilter(typeof(AuthorizationRequiredAttribute))]
        public IActionResult Message()
        {
            return Ok("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```